# launching ipyparallel cluster across multiple nodes using MPI

Tags: ipython, mpi, cluster-computing, ipython-parallel

I am trying to start a ipyparallel cluster using MPI.

The ipcluster_config has following lines modified as such:

```
c.MPILauncher.mpi_cmd = ['mpiexec']
c.MPIControllerLauncher.controller_args = ['--ip=*']
c.MPILauncher.mpi_args = ["-machinefile", "~/mpi_hosts"]
```

The ipcontroller_config.py is configured as such:

```
c.HubFactory.engine_ip = '*'
c.HubFactory.ip = '*'
c.HubFactory.client_ip = '*'
```

However, when I launch the cluster using command 

`ipcluster start  --profile mpi -n 2`

it fails with following message

```
Engines shutdown early, they probably failed to connect.
You can set this by adding "--ip='*'" to your ControllerLauncher.controller_args
```

Not sure how to debug further.

Comment: Try running `ipcluster start  --profile mpi -n 2 --debug` and post the logs from the same

Comment: Thanks Tarun. This helps. It seems ipcluster is not able to find mpiexec. I need to figure out how to configure ipcluster so it loads the modules.

Comment: Did you install the MPI package?

Comment: I am on a PBS cluster environment. I have to do module load to see mpiexec in the path. I guess when ipcluster is launching engines on remote nodes, it does not do "module load". I am looking into configs to see if there is any place to specify that.